# Push all rows into single row and column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),c.ClientId) + ','
FROM [dbo].[tblClient] c
```

This returns 17,000 + rows. Is there a way to make all these rows return as 1 value? For example:

```
 6A7A24CD-061C-4653-9790-882D90F81E1D,0980722E-6E96-4498-B3BB-BFB4CA60EAC6,etc etc etc.
```

I am trying to use this as a parameter for testing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: Is there wiki for this kind of thing yet? Must be one of the most commonly-asked questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

does this work for you?

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @v = ''

SELECT 
    @v = @v +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),c.ClientId) + ','
FROM [dbo].[tblClient] c
WHERE c.ClientId IS NOT NULL


SELECT  @v
```

**Note**: Just be aware that if you add an ORDER BY that it is not guaranteed to sort it, in that case use xml path as shown in [Remus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364557/push-all-rows-into-single-row-and-column/7364626#7364626)

See also: [Concatenate Values From Multiple Rows Into One Column Ordered](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Concatenate_Values_From_Multiple_Rows_Into_One_Column_Ordered)

Comment: That will work. It wont be able to store all my values but it will work for what I need. Thanks.

Comment: varchar(max) will go up to 2 billion characters

Comment: I thought it was 8,000 characters?

Comment: varchar(8000) = 8000, varchar(max) goes up to 2GB

Answer (score 4):

The article covers a number of techniques at your disposal: [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/). My favorite technique is the black-box XML method:

```
SELECT cast(c.ClientId as varchar(20)) + ','
FROM [dbo].[tblClient] c
for xml path(''), type;
```

Comment: +1 The other method will possibly break if an `ORDER BY` clause is added as [described here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us)

Comment: Yes ORDER is not guaranteed, since I didn't see ORDER BY in his query I gave him this version....I have both versions here: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Concatenate_Values_From_Multiple_Rows_Into_One_Column_Ordered...I will add this to my answer just in case

Comment: There is no order by. I just needed to use it to populate a parameter list.